# Steps to fetch Google MAP API v1 key in android

Tags: android

I have been trying to use google map in my project, but i am not able to find proper documentation on how to get the api key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps for api v1

step 1
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/

step2 create map key
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey

Step 3> Go to android folder location in command prompt

```
cd C:\Users\Iotasol Inc\.android
```

Step 4> Run command

```
F:\devtools\jdk6\bin\keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Step 5> It will produce below output

```
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: 4 Mar, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 51344e4a
Valid from: Mon Mar 04 13:03:30 IST 2013 until: Wed Feb 25 13:03:30 IST 2043
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  12:91:23:19:31:23:33:66:84:1F:1E:25:05:F4:14:65
         SHA1: 32:CC:11:31:38:B9:74:FA:23:Z6:24:A6:1B:34:A6:92:1B:22:32
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 3
```

Step 6> Go to key signup page
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/maps-api-signup

Step 7 > insert MD5 : key

12:91:23:89:31:23:23:66:85:1F:1E:22:05:F4:14:65

step 8> Copy the key generated and used it in your mapview element in your layout xml
like

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapViewx"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="***********Your KEY **************"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

Comment: i followed these steps to use it

Comment: bro Can I able to add the pin mark image over a Image View using method Google map API v1

Answer (score 1):

API v1 is deprected. Since 3 days ago you cannot get an API key 
from : 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey

> Note: Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API as been officially
>   deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. This means that from March 3rd,
>   2013 you will no longer be able to request an API key for this
>   version. **This means that from March 3rd, 2013** you will **no longer be able to request an API key for this version.**

So, I would suggest to migrate to V2:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer get a V1 key instaed you have to use V2. [Here is the developer guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). It has a step by step way to get the API key.