# Why am I getting an error: package com.google.android.maps does not exist?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am building an Android app and I keep getting this error...

`/code bases/2016/app/src/main/java/com/app/apps/android/appt/object/Route.java:3: error: package com.google.android.maps does not exist
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;`

Android studio is red on the maps part...

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
```

This is my full Gradle file...

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter();
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
        // quickly to Android tooling updates
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.5'

        //classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'

    dexOptions {
        //maxProcessCount 2
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'myApp'
            keyPassword '2012'
            storeFile file('/myApp')
            storePassword '2012'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myApp.apps.android.maint"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 21
        versionName '3.51'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }

    productFlavors {
        //releaseDev {}
        //releaseIOSTest {}
        releaseTest {}
        releaseLive {}
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.2'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.15'
    compile 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 3):

You should upgrade your google repository library, and change the following code:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

And:

```
compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.15'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
```

Read more here https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: ok I have done that now this import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint; is coming up red where it says 'maps' any ideas?

Comment: Remove  import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint; because it pointed to old google maps library.
Use this instead: import com.google.android.maps.geopoint. 
Don't forget to check all the old google maps import line.

Comment: Hi, the one you provided also goes red  - is this anything to do with it?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246304/steps-to-fetch-google-map-api-v1-key-in-android

Comment: Not exactly. the error you've got is related to old api.
Try to remove first all related maps import line. Then on the code red lined, press alt + Enter to auto import library.